# Как сделать проверку есть ли в массиве(из запроса) type['лекции']=on или off

Tags: mysql, веб-программирование, php, массивы, sql

```
$lec_type_for_link=mysql_query("select *    from `ведомость` where 'группа'='$gg' 'дисциплина'='$dd'");
    $type=mysql_fetch_array($lec_type_for_link) || die(mysql_error());
    while($type=mysql_fetch_array($lec_type_for_link))
    {echo "лекции ". $type['лекции']."<>";
    echo "лабы ".$type['лабы']."<>";
    echo "практики".$type['практики']."<>";
    echo "контрольные ".$type['контрольные']."<>";
    echo "дз".$type['дз']."<>";
    echo "летучки ".$type['летучки']."<>";
    echo "курсовая ".$type['курсовая']."<>";
    echo "премия_лектора ".$type['премия_лектора']."<>";
    echo "премия_курсовых".$type['премия_курсовых']."<>";
    echo "экзамен или зачет ".$type['экзамен_или_зачет']."<>";
    echo "конспект ".$type['конспект']."<>";}
```

Comment: странный запрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($type['лекции'] !== '') {  
  if($type['лекции']==='on'){  
    ...  
  }  
  elseif($type['лекции']==='of'){   
    ...  
  }  
  else {  
  echo 'Значение задано неверно';  
  }  
}
else {
echo 'Нет значения';
}
```